# Second preimage resistance using MD4 AND MD5

Tags: hash, cryptography

Let's say we have the following:
- String: str
- MD4 hash of the string: MD4(str)
- MD5 hash of the string: MD5(str)

MD4 and MD5 are cryptographically "broken" algorithms, meaning it is not difficult to:

1) find str_2 where MD4(str) = MD4(str_2) (i.e. attack on MD4)
2) find str_3 where MD5(str) = MD5(str_3) (i.e. attack on MD5)

But how hard would it be to:

3) find str_4 where MD4(str) = MD4(str_4) ***AND*** MD5(str) = MD5(str_4) 
(i.e. attack on MD4 and MD5 simultaneously)?

The obvious (probably not very efficient) way would be to:

1) Find a string STR where MD4(STR) = MD4(str)
2) Check if MD5(STR) = MD5(str)
3) If so, we're done. If not, go back to step 1 and satisfy step 1 with a different string.

But the above algorithm doesn't seem fast to me (or is it?). So is it true that a string hashed by both MD4 and MD5 would be quite safe from a second preimage attack?

**EDIT:**
(1) The main concern is enhancing second pre-image resistance

(2) The main motivation is not to use outdated hashes for today's applications. Rather, it is two-fold: **first**, I am anticipating the day that hashes considered secure today become broken. For example, If I use only SHA-2, then the day it becomes broken is the same day I will become very worried about my data. But if I use SHA-2 and BCrypt, then even if both become individually broken, it may still be unfeasible to defeat the second pre-image resistance of concat(Sha2_hash, Bcrypt_Hash). **Second**, I want to reduce the chance of accidental collision (server thinks two inputs are the same because two hashes JUST so happens to be the same)

Comment: Why don't you just use a better hashing algorithm?

Comment: I used MD4 and MD5 as hypotheticals. The main motivation is as follows: If I only use one hash (e.g. SHA-2), then the day that SHA-2 becomes broken will be the same day I become very concerned about my data security. But if I use two hashes that are considered secure today (SHA-2 and bcrypt), then even if one gets broken (say SHA-2), I still have decent protection left and have more time to implement a another system (say using bcrypt and some future SHA version).

Comment: SHA-2 and bcrypt is a really weird combo, since SHA-2 is a general purpose hash, and bcrypt a password hash. If you want to combine two general purpose hashes, SHA-2 and SHA-3 is probably the best choice (once SHA-3 is actually standardized)

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what you are planning to use this for? As a sidenote, this topic may be better suited to [crypto.stackexchange.com](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yep, a file store. The hash "uniquely" identifies a file. I need to prevent against two situations: (1) others producing a different file with the same hash, resulting in both files being deduplicated when they're not supposed to be, and (2) enhancing accidental collision by some number of bits

Comment: @Aaron Ahh... OK, now that makes more sense. See my update.

Comment: @Aaron The flaw in your logic is that you are assuming that a weaker hash is no more likely to be broken than a stronger one. Would you rather worry that a hash might be broken in the future or actually have a hash that's in fact broken *now*? If you're sensible, you want to get as much security out of each bit. SHA-2 gets you more security from each bit than either MD5 or MD4 does. So each MD5 or MD4 bit that could have been a SHA-2 bit makes your security that much weaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing doesn't improve security as much as you think. The resulting (M+N) bit value is actually weaker than the output of a hash that natively generates (M+N) bits of output. This answer on [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/270/guarding-against-cryptanalytic-breakthroughs-combining-multiple-hash-functions) goes a little deeper if you want to know more details.

But the bottom line is that when constructing a hash function whose output is the concatenation of other hash functions, the output you get is, at best, as strong as the strongest constituent hash.

And I have to ask why even use MD4 or MD5 and go to this trouble to begin with? Use SHA-3. If you want to feel "extra safe" then calculate the margin of safety that you feel comfortable with, and increase it by some percentage. That is, if you feel that 384 bits are enough, then go for 512.

---

So, with some more information about you are trying to do, which is to use the file contents to generate both a "quick checksum" value and generate a unique locator/identifier for the file at the same time I still think that choosing a single hash is the better approach.

If you insist on using two hash functions, then I would submit that instead of concatenating two hashes the better approach would be to instead use a HMAC using two different hash functions/algorithms. Please note, that I do not have a rigorous proof that this works better, or that this construct won't generate horrible output. So take it with a grain of salt:

Let `H1` and `H2` be two cryptographically secure hash functions, and let `P` be your input data. Then, the hash & file identifier for your file is given by the construct:

```
HMAC (K,P) = H1((KGEN(P) ⊕ PAD1) ∥ H1((KGEN(P) ⊕ PAD2) ∥ P)))
```

Where

```
KGEN (P) = H2(P)
```

Comment: The answer in the link suggests that with hash concatenation, (1) collision resistance will be better and (2) (first) pre-image resistance will be only as strong as the weakest hash (which makes obvious sense). What if I only needed to enhance second pre-image resistance?

As for why MD4/MD5, please see my response to the comment on the main question. That reply also addresses the advantage of using two hashes (one M bits, one N bits) compared to using one M+N hash.

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda more difficult. Because one would need to calculate collision for MD4 and simultaneously for MD5. But kinda is a lame term in cryptography. Rolling your own security scheme is the enemy #1. However, there are examples, when people chain algorithms, such as DES => 3 DES or TrueCrypt allows chaining several encryption algorithms or PBKDF2 key derivation runs the same algorithms N times.

Seriously, if you need a strong hash - use SHA2 and onwards.

The problem with finding MD4 and MD5 hash collisions is that it's possible to make a chain of devices that would allow attacker to linearly scale number of attack attempts, and given large enough budget this sounds plausible.

Comment: I agree that rolling a custom security scheme is inadvisable. But I am simply using two separate schemes, so in the worst case, it would be as good as the least secure one. Also the use of MD4/MD5 is just hypothetical; please see my reply to the comment on the main question at the top.+